# Make Arrow symbol to plus(+) and minus(-) in Kendo Tree view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am new to Kendo-UI, the below is my sample code to display the data in kendo tree view. The result is coming fine but it is showing arrow symbol when expand and collapse the menu, instead of that i want to make it as a plus(+) and minus(-):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  animation: false,
  dataSource: [
    { text: "foo", items: [
      { text: "bar", items: [{text:"car"}] }
    ] }
  ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to customize treeview icons via css:

```css
.k-treeview .k-minus {
     background: url('../Images/your_minus_img.png')center center;
}
.k-treeview .k-plus{
     background: url('../Images/your_plus_img.png')center center;
}
```

See a live sample [here on Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ugUVi)

Comment: Thank you@Andrea, but it is giving "Failed to load given url", because it is taking from "http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/" not from my path

Comment: @majji added a link to a live sample on dojo